# Tener dos plantillas distintas (una para front-end y otra para back-end)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Necesito tener dos plantillas distintas para mi proyecto, una es para el front-end la cual tiene su propio menú y diseño, por otra parte tengo otra plantilla para el back-end que también tiene su propio menú y diseño, la gracia está en hacer coexistir estos dos templates.

El usuario llega al index de la página y puede ver cierta información, una vez registrado puede ingresar al dashboard (back-end) en el cual tiene acceso a otra información.

¿Cómo puedo hacer coexistir estos dos templates con barras de menú diferente en Laravel?, cual sería el orden de las vistas/carpetas para este fin?

Soy nuevo en Laravel y ocupo la versión 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Confundes conceptos, aunque te he entendido perfectamente con la explicación posterior, vayamos por partes:

**Front-end**

> La parte de cara al cliente, lo que se muestra en el navegador de la persona
>   que se conecta a tu web, compuesto por HTML, CSS y javascript en la mayoría de los casos. (Tanto tu index como tu dashboard son front-end)

**Back-end**

> La parte oculta al cliente, toda la programación interna que se encuentra en el servidor, php, java, .net... etc.

Aclarado un poco esto, yo por mi parte lo que hago es separar estas dos cosas, es decir creo dos carpetas diferentes, en la default entraran todos sin excepción, y en la admin redirigirá con el enrutador a un login (o a comprobar si hay sesión iniciada y si no login), en esa carpeta el html y el css que usaré para el menú será totalmente distinta a la de mi carpeta default.

En resumen, 2 carpetas con html y css distintos para tu caso.

Comment: Entiendo perfecto, lo que me confunde un poco es el archivo app.blade.php dentro de la carpeta layouts, que por lo visto es el carga el contenido en laravel. Creo que debería borrar esa carpeta, crear dos carpetas nuevas una llamada backend y otra frontend con los css correspondientes, luego en las rutas manejas el index/welcome del sitio, por ahí creo que va (vengo del mundo de rails)

Comment: En este caso, el login y register (las vistas) están en el default que llamas tu, luego que se ingresa, el usuario sigue viendo la pagina index /welcome, pero esta vez le aparece en el menú la opción de dashboard, al hacer click es dirigido a al dashboard de la app con otro css y todo eso.

Comment: Si eso mismo, dos carpetas distintas, con dos controladores diferentes, guardas en sesion los datos del login y mandas al usuario a /dashboard y ahi compruebas si hay datos en sesion y si son correctos y le muestras el dashboard.